# How to mark pin as driven in KiCad?

Tags: kicad

In my schematic output of MOSFET is driving USB power, however KiCad thinks that this MOSFET pin is passive and complains that USB is not driven.

On top level schematic USB_OUT is connected to VCC, and USB_5V is connected to PWR_FLAG.

[image: usb driver]
[image: usb connector]

Same problem with USB shielding. All shields in my USB connectors are connected, and they are not connected to my circuit (I assume USB host will connect shield).

How I can mark such pins as "Driven"? I think PWR_FLAG does not really tell purpose (as pin is not power bus).

Comment: Why yo do not use global power flags from the power library?

Comment: I have multiple such connectors and driver circuits. By using hierarchical sheets I can route them correctly in main circuit.

Comment: Also do you think that shield should be marked as driven with power pin?

Comment: I think that you should connect the shield to the GND and use global power flags like GND. If you want to name them as special names then create your own global power flag library.

Comment: @BahtiyarBayram if I connect shield of usb connector in my device, and so does host then shield will be connected in two places and current may flow between the connections (please note that shield is already connected by host device).